# json string parsing error

Tags: javascript, json

I am doing an ajax call to get data from the server in a json format. The json data when retrieved on the client side is in the format below

```
        '{
    "rows": {
        "content": ["ncoding=\"UTF-8\"?>",
        "ncoding=\"UTF-8\"?>",
        "ncoding=\"UTF-8\"?>",
        "ncoding=\"UTF-8\"?>",
        "ncoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"],
        "root": [{}], "form_data":[{}]
      }
}'
```

The single quote is becoming very annoying. As When doing json.parse, it is giving the error "Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 0". Once i remove the single quote, it automatically converts to a JSON object in the chrome console.  On the server side, the data is without the single quotes.

any idea how to remove the single quote?

Thanks, 
Ashley

Comment: How are you returning the object you might be returning it as string try to return as object.

Comment: fix the server code to NOT send a `'`

Comment: if you can't change the server, request TEXT (not JSON) - if it's in a variable called `text`, you can `var data = JSON.parse(text.substr(1,text.length-2))`

Comment: @Leopard I am returning a json string. at server side, when debugging, the single quote is not there.

Comment: @JaromandaX will try that.

Comment: Not sure if its just formatting on your example json but maybe add a trim before the substring. As there appears to be whitespace as well.

Comment: @JaromandaX Amazing. thanks a lot. Any advise in the future on how to return json data?

Comment: make sure your server does it correctly